# Identify Request : A Girl Falls Down (a Well?) And Wakes Up In Alternate Dimension (maybe dead?)?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, character-identification

So I am usually good about movies but my daughter presented me with this info and it is so familiar but I can't place the movie (or possibly part of a TV show).  Can you help?

> Girl falls down (possibly a well) and seems to be in an alternate
>   reality (might be dead-ish) and she reverts to a like caveman style. 
>   Parents find her but are it is like they see her in a fishbowl or cage
>   or zoo and can't communicate with her.

That is all she remembers.  I might actually be thinking Child of Glass but did a trailer for my daughter and she says no.  But that might be what is familiar to me.  Anyone have any other thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: One of these? https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3zwby2/tomt_movie_80s_maybe_90s_horror_type_film_about_a/

Answer (score 3):

This sort of reminds me of an episode of *Star Trek: Deep space Nine*, "Time's Orphan" 20 May 1998.

Molly O'Brien falls into a hole and goes through a time warp.

This also reminds me to a lesser degree of the *Twilight Zone* episode "Little Girl Lost", March 16, 1962, in which a little girl enters an alternate dimension and her parents can hear her but not see or touch her.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like how Kagome winds up in the world of spirits and demons in *Inuyasha* -- though I recall her climbing a ladder up and down the well that connects her world (parents, school, etc.) to that one.  I've seen only a few episodes, not including the beginning, so she might have fallen that first time.

I don't recall her parents finding her in a "look only" manner, however, and there was nothing "cave-man" about her in the spirit world; in fact, she continued to wear her school uniform even as she was falling in love with the titular half-demon.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like Inuyasha. 
 It's an anime or japanese animation. Kagome [current time] lives in her family house with a shine, one day the family's cat goes insede the a small cabin where there is a well, called the bone eater well.  She gets close to it and a demon grabs her.  She theb wakes up inside the well comes out in middle of a forest. As she walks and meets the village realizes she is in the past.
She meets a half demon boy called Inuyasha that is stuck to a tree with an arrow....